# Xcode9 expand/collapse if or switch {} is missing

Tags: xcode, xcode9

when update to xcode9 ,i found the if or swith {} can not be fold,any one know how to fold "{}" in the read area

[image]

Comment: Hey, can you please mark answer as accepted? it took about two years! The Stack overflow community relies on questions and answers, votes, and acceptances.

Answer (score 0):

It Seems that, fold unfold options from sidebar on editor are removed in xCode 9.

But you can still do it from Editor.

by following way you can achieve the same. (You can always use the **shortcuts**)

Editor -> Code Folding -> Fold/Unfold

[image: Editor -> Code Folding -> Fold/Unfold]

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: this only can fold  or unfold  the area of function

Answer (score 0):

It's back in Xcode 10. You can turn it on from menu Xcode -> Preferences -> Text Editing tab -> Edit tab -> check show: code folding rebbon

[image: Xcode 10 preferences]